# How to Inherit Arrowheds size?

Tags: core-language, scoping, graphics

I'm trying to write a `Module` that produces some arrows with custom `Arrowhead` shapes. However, I want the code external to the `Module` to set the `Arrowhead` size. However, using the word `Inherited` for size throws an error.

```
circle = Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]];
arrow = Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}];
g = Graphics[
  {Arrowheads[.2],
    {Arrowheads[{{.2(*Inherited*), 1, circle}}], arrow}
}]
```

Obviously, I don't understand how `Inherited` works and I'm hoping that someone will show how to use it correctly.

Comment: `Inherited` appears to only work for options. `Arrowheads[]` is a function, not an option. What about using `Automatic`? Or making it an argument to your module like `customArrow[size_] := Module[{}, circle = ...; arrow = ...; g = Graphics[{Arrowheads[.2], {Arrowheads[{{size, 1, circle}}], arrow}}]`?